# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync timeout when released to IIS7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I'm having problems with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync timing out after releasing my code to IIS7.0.

Via my dev environment everything works as expected. I get shown the Google permission screen and the code creates the expected token file in App_data. I can then insert and update calendar entries. 
However when i release the code I get a Request timed out error from GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync.

I've manually copied a token file created from my dev environment onto the web server and the code works fine. I can create events in the calendar.

I've monitored the firewall and nothing is getting blocked.

If i remove the contents of the token file on the web server. I am not prompted to re-authorize and im back to the request timeout.

Anyone got any suggestions on whats going wrong?

```
ClientSecrets client = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = SessionState.SystemSettings[SystemSettingKey.GoogleAccountClientId].Value,
    ClientSecret = SessionState.SystemSettings[SystemSettingKey.GoogleAccountClientSecret].Value

};

IList<string> scopes = new List<string>();
scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);
var credPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");          
var credential =
    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(client, scopes, account, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true))
        .Result;

// Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "App1"
};
```

Comment: Does the request execute and not return?

Comment: On the dev environment it executes and returns, however when its compiled and installed on webserver it just sits there waiting for the return. However nothing is blocked on the firewall from what i can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna go on a huntch feeling here and say you have yourself a classic deadlock scenario, since you're [blocking on an async method](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) here:

```
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                              client, 
                              scopes, 
                              account,                         
                              CancellationToken.None,
                              new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

You shouldn't use `.Result` on async methods, you should always asynchronously wait using `await`:

```
public async Task AuthorizeAsync()
{
   ClientSecrets client = new ClientSecrets
   {
       ClientId = SessionState.
                        SystemSettings[SystemSettingKey.GoogleAccountClientId].Value,
       ClientSecret = SessionState.
                        SystemSettings[SystemSettingKey.GoogleAccountClientSecret].Value

   };

   IList<string> scopes = new List<string>();
   scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);
   var credPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");  

   var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                 client, 
                                 scopes, 
                                 account,
                                 CancellationToken.None,
                                 new FileDataStore(credPath, true));

   // Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
   BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
   {
      HttpClientInitializer = credential,
      ApplicationName = "App1"
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. i think its on the right lines as it seems a few have a similar issue. Thanks for the pointer